# Why does fs.watch only trigger when I open the file being watched?

Tags: node.js

I'm currently trying to implement a live file feed in which writes data to the connected client in the web. This works perfectly fine if I'm editing the document directly, updates are sent immediately.

Instead of me manually writing to the file, i created another process to handle that step. The issue I'm having is that when my process writes to this file, the changes are not being detected. Unless i explicitly open the file,the changes made are not being detected.

*I also know that fs.watch is inconsistent*, but what would be the difference between manually editing and automation?

```
// function to start process and check for changes in file
const start = function() {
    fs.open(file, 'r', (err, fd) => {
        if(err){
            return setTimeout(start, 1000)
        }
        fs.watch(file,(event, filename) => {
            if(event === "change"){
                console.log('change detected');
                // function that sends client messages
                sendMessage(fd);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here is the code that automates the process of writing to the file:

```
const fs    = require('fs');
const file = 'file.txt';

const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(file, {
    flags:"a"
});

const cleanBuffer = function(len) {
    let buf = Buffer.alloc(len);
    buf.fill('\0');
    return buf;
}

const check = function() {
    let newData = `data being written`;
    const buffer = cleanBuffer(newData.length);
    buffer.write(newData, 'ascii');
    writeStream.write(buffer);
    setTimeout(check, 10000);
}
```

I tried to view the file from file explorer and whenever I access the folder this file is contained in, the change is detected...is this actually watching the file?

Comment: Can you share what automated process in particular is modifying the file?

Comment: @Jamie_D automated process is now included

Comment: I'm thinking that since the file always contains "data being written", FS Watch doesn't believe the file has changed. Try making `newData`  a random string for testing ....

Comment: Here's a (package for that)[https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomstring] then `newData = randomstring.generate();`

Comment: @Jamie_D I tried your suggestion w/ the random string and the behavior has not changed. I still have to explicitly open the file for the `fs.watch` to detect the changes made.

Comment: After doing some research on FS Watch, there are many that are saying that it only detects changes on a folder level so you may want to use [Chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) or [Hound](https://github.com/gforceg/node-hound) as an FS Watch replacement.

Comment: ... actually, both those packages are fs.watch wrappers and not actually replacements

Comment: @Jamie_D, hey thanks for the help, I found a solution. Reference my answer please. Also should upvote question so others are aware

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and it looks as though w/ windows this is working as expected because

> On Windows systems, this feature depends on ReadDirectoryChangesW

I had to change the function to use fs.watchFile instead, which is working for me although it is recommended to use fs.watch.

More can be read here: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v11.x/api/fs.html#fs_availability

The code now reflects as:

```
// function to start process and check for changes in tweets file
const start = function() {
    fs.open(file, 'r', (err, fd) => {
        if(err){
            return setTimeout(start, 1000)
        }
        fs.watchFile(file,(curr, prev) => {
            if(curr.mtime !== prev.mtime){
                console.log('change detected');
                sendMessage(fd);
            }
        });
    });
}
```